# NullPointerException issue with setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I've looked across many similar questions and tried to implement the solutions given. None seem to remove the 'NullPointerException' that breaks the app I'm trying to build. I have always used this method for buttons without any problems, and I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Below is my simple java class, where the 'setOnClickListener' method triggers a warning.

```
public class pennState extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Button buttonNext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.penn_state_1);

    buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(myHandler1);

}
View.OnClickListener myHandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(pennState.this, pennState2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
}
```

I've checked the id of the xml properties and everything seems to be accurate. Any help is welcome.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonConfirm"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView95" />
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: we can help you better way if you post your error log.

Comment: I don't think so. It is really obvious and evident that the myHandler1 variable is throwing the NPE.

Comment: *where the 'setOnClickListener' method triggers a warning.*. It is lint warning you that it could potentially a NPE. If you declared the widget in your layout, you can ignore it

Answer (score 3):

You are calling that variable BEFORE declaring it. And also put that myHandler1 in the onCreate().

You can also add this property to the xml tag

```
android:onClick="myMethod"
```

And then declare this method

```
public void myMethod(View view){}
```

And put what you want to do when the button is clicked between the curly brackets.

Comment: Firstly, this isn't the problem. Secondly, if you're going to flag a question as a duplicate, you shouldn't be answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable declaration above, alongside with the button, and initialize it in `onCreate`:

```
public class pennState extends AppCompatActivity  {
Button buttonNext;
View.OnClickListener myHandler1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.penn_state_1);

    myHandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(pennState.this, pennState2.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }
};

    buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(myHandler1);
}
```

Comment: And... what did I say before you?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to load new answer while I looked at other tabs, and you answered. Don't get salty :)

Comment: It also happens to me ;D Don't worry

Comment: Gonna give you a +1 as a sorry :D enjoy bro, keep coding!

Comment: Thanks, So do ypu!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `new OnClickListener` to the `setOnClickListener` of the button instead of declaring this as a local variable. You could do something like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.penn_state_1);

        buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(pennState.this, pennState2.class);
            startActivity(i);
          }
        });
    }
```